# Firebase storage allow firebase function to upload files without authentication

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is there a way to allow only a firebase function to upload files to firebase storage without authentication?

Comment: If you use the admin sdk in your cloud function, I think you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload to files to Storage in Cloud Functions for Firebase, you are using the Node.js SDK for Cloud Storage and your code accesses Storage with elevated privileges. This SDK does not follow Firebase's security rules for your Storage bucket, so it can upload files no matter what rules you set.

So if you use this rule:

```
allow write: if false;
```

Your Cloud Functions will be able to upload files, but nobody using a client-side SDK in your app will be able to.